I create a Next app using typescript and tailwindcss i am unable to display my Image
I create a Next app using typescript and tailwindcss i am unable to display my Image location in Public/assests/images/me/me.png i also created a types folder in which i created a images.d.ts file
my console view
my code
import React from 'react';
import MyImage from "@/public/assets/images/me/me.png";
console.log(MyImage);

function Profile() {
  return (
    <div className='flex items-center gap-x-2 transition-colors duration-75 text-primary-foreground'>
      {/* photo  */}
      <div className='relative w-[100px] h-[100px] rounded-full flex justify-center items-center bg-gradient-to-r from-blue-joust to-green-benzol'>
        <img src={MyImage} alt='Sujeet Photo' className='w-[95px] h-[95px] border-[0.2vw] border-blue-cosmos rounded-full object-cover'/>
        {/* Online */}
        <div className='w-3 h-3 rounded-full bg-green-benzol border-blue-cosmos absolute right-0 bottom-5'></div>
      </div>
      <div className="text-3xl font-medium">SUJEET SINGHANIYA</div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Profile;


which folder you have picture. is it in public/ folder

As @alphaxx has demonstrated in the answer, make sure to use the native Image tag with nextjs to get all the image optimizations

Nextjs provides an image component, try to use that for image optimization(Also recommended by the Nextjs itself). Comes from next/image, import it and use it.

You should use MyImage.src instead of directly using the static import MyImage itself.
<img src={MyImage.src} />

But in next.js, a better approach would be to use the Image component, which can directly use MyImage itself:
import Image from "next/image";

...

<Image alt="Sujeet Photo" src={MyImage} />


Nextjs serve static files like images under a folder called public folder.
Instead of Importing the image relocate the Image file to the public folder and Then pass it location in the src attribute of <Image/> component
Reference :
https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/optimizing/static-assets

You have to assign your src property as follows:
<img src={yourImportedImage.src} />

Just keep in mind the recommended way is to use the Image component instead. It's provided by Next.js and it comes with pre-built optimizations (e.g. accessibility, SEO, etc).
If you use the Image component, you can assign it's source property directly, like so:
<Image
  src={yourImportedImage}
  alt="Describe your image..."        
/>


here you can show you image like it is because you are using html img tag so do it like no need to import
<img src='/assets/images/me/me.png' alt='Sujeet Photo' className='w-[95px] h-[95px] border-[0.2vw] border-blue-cosmos rounded-full object-cover'/>

